# makeKeyAndVisible & makeKeyWindow - uiwindow in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwindow

In every application,

there is always written as [window makeKeyAndVisible];

What is mean by makeKey?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The key window is the window which will receive user interaction.

You might take a look at this:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/ChangingMainKeyWindow.html

Answer (score 5):

This means that this is the window that accepts keyboard input. This matches similar nomenclature on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 3):

This method call performs a critical function. If you omit it then the top level view to the window will not be autoresized however you have set the springs and struts. Took me a while to figure that out: if the in-call status bar resizing is not happening, check to see that the window is marked as key.

Answer (score 2):

Makes the receiver the key window and makes that window visible.

This is a convenience method to make the receiver the main window and displays it in front of other windows. You can also hide and reveal a window using the inherited hidden property of UIView.

**source**: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html